# Swinging a sword in Xcode with Sprite Kit

Tags: collision-detection, ios, physics, xcode, spritekit

I'm working on making an RPG in Xcode, and I'm having a major gameplay issue when it comes to having my character swing his sword in a way that is realistic and gameplay compatible.

Right now, when the player taps the screen and the sword is in one of the player's hand, it rotates the upright sword 90 degrees.  The sword which is a parent of the player floats in front of the player because of a collision issue

I'm looking for any advice anyone can give on how to add a sword to the game and have it swing in a way that looks somewhat realistic and can damage enemies that are more than a single pixel away from the player

Comment: I assume this is a top-down game, as your description would be odd otherwise.  Do you mean the sword is the child of the player?   Would an animation not serve your purposes, rather than a rotating sprite?  Have you looked at the sample SpriteKit game, called "Adventure"?

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why your sword is only damaging enemies a single pixel away?  That seems like odd behavior that I can only imagine would result from a very small or misaligned SKPhysicsBody

Comment: It is top down.  I was trying to use animation, but the size of the player remained constant so it just made a swinging motion.  What I meant was one pixel away was that running the swing animation would make the swinging motion, but unless an enemy was literally on top of me, there would be no collision like you should get with a long sword that can reach far out.

Comment: Basically, I want the sword to swing beyond the player's body

Comment: How large is the sprite before the animation, and how large afterwards?

Comment: I didn't think the size of the sprite could be changed. Whenever I run an animations it seems to shrink itself to the size of the sprite

Comment: What I mean to say is, is your "upright sword" a very small sprite, as if the character was holding it vertically?  Then when it's swung, is the sword extended outward, horizontally away from the character?

Comment: That's what I tried doing with the rotate action, but I was trying to find a different way

Comment: I mean, could it be that your SKPhysicsBody starts off very small, because of a small sprite, and stays small even during the animation?

Comment: The size is constant during animations

Answer (score 1):

I think most of your problems might be solved by understanding the use of [category masks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14).  Simply set the masks to ignore contact and collision between the sword and player categories.

Specifically, this is done by assigning unsigned integers to the *categoryBitMask*, *collisionBitMask*, and *contactBitMask* properties of the **SKPhysicsBody** of the **SKSpriteNode** in question.

- *categoryBitMask* is the category of the physics body (e.g. swordCategory)
- *contactBitMask* is the product of the ORed categories of the types of nodes you want to test for contact (e.g. enemyCategory | breakableCategory | wallCategory)
- *collisionBitMask* is the product of the ORed categories of the types of nodes you want to resolve collision (e.g. enemyCategory | wallCategory)

Comment: I am well aware of category masks and have directed both not to interact with one another

Comment: I assumed they were because you said the sword "floats" because of a collision issue.  If the problem isn't that the sword is colliding with the player, what is the "collision issue" you're having?

Comment: Ok for some reason it seems to act as if the monster's bit mask is the same as the players

Comment: Make sure you remember to set every physics body's category, or it might default to a specific category, which in your case might be the player's category

Comment: I'm checking each one (and there are quite a few), but they all seem to be set so far

Comment: I have the sword's collision and contact bit mask set to monster category, but it's detecting collisions between sword category and playercategory

Comment: Just make sure the two categories are distinct and unique.  Use a log or print function or the XCode debugging features to see what the bit masks are at different points.  It sounds like they're either accidentally equivalent, or they're being assigned instead of checked for equivalency